# Aggregate Result over a Table in Impala

Tags: aggregate, impala

After investigating a lot on aggregates function in Impala, I have to accept that I'm completely lost.
I have the following Table:

[image: Input Table]

And I want an aggregated result as follow:

[image: Results]

can Someone give me a light on which function shall I use to get that result?

Thank

I'm looking for the functions to be used in the select statement to get the aggregated result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all` to calculate count of each columns - COLA,B,C...

```
select 
'COLA',
sum( case when cola='Match' then 1 else 0 end) as Matches,
sum( case when cola='Mismatch' then 1 else 0 end) as Mismatches
from mytable
union all
select 
'COLB',
sum( case when colb='Match' then 1 else 0 end) as Matches,
sum( case when colb='Mismatch' then 1 else 0 end) as Mismatches
from mytable
union all
select 
'COLC',
sum( case when colc='Match' then 1 else 0 end) as Matches,
sum( case when colc='Mismatch' then 1 else 0 end) as Mismatches
from mytable
```